# Getting USB Version through WMI Classes

Tags: powershell, usb, wmi

I am trying to query the USB Device for the USB Descriptor which will store information regarding the USB Version, Device ID, PID, VID etc. I only need the USB Version.

**Here is the PowerShell Code so far:**

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.Management, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

$Man = New-Object System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_USBHub")

[System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection]$Devs = $Man.GetInstances()
echo $Devs
```

**The output I am getting is:**

```
__GENUS                     : 2
__CLASS                     : Win32_USBHub
__SUPERCLASS                : CIM_USBHub
__DYNASTY                   : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH                   : Win32_USBHub.DeviceID="USB\\VID_0781&PID_5567\\4C530000120619102080"
__PROPERTY_COUNT            : 28
__DERIVATION                : {CIM_USBHub, CIM_USBDevice, CIM_LogicalDevice, CIM_LogicalElement...}
__SERVER                    : APPS-SD-AUTO-PC
__NAMESPACE                 : root\cimv2
__PATH                      : \\APPS-SD-AUTO- PC\root\cimv2:Win32_USBHub.DeviceID="USB\\VID_0781&PID_5567\\4C530000120619102080"
Availability                : 
Caption                     : USB Mass Storage Device
ClassCode                   : 
ConfigManagerErrorCode      : 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig     : False
CreationClassName           : Win32_USBHub
CurrentAlternateSettings    : 
CurrentConfigValue          : 
Description                 : USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID                    : USB\VID_0781&PID_5567\4C530000120619102080
ErrorCleared                : 
ErrorDescription            : 
GangSwitched                : 
InstallDate                 : 
LastErrorCode               : 
Name                        : USB Mass Storage Device
NumberOfConfigs             : 
NumberOfPorts               : 
PNPDeviceID                 : USB\VID_0781&PID_5567\4C530000120619102080
PowerManagementCapabilities : 
PowerManagementSupported    : 
ProtocolCode                : 
Status                      : OK
StatusInfo                  : 
SubclassCode                : 
SystemCreationClassName     : Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName                  : APPS-SD-AUTO-PC
USBVersion                  :
```

Here `USBVersion` is coming as an empty field. Can anyone suggest a solution?

I have tried with `Win32_usbDeviceController` but that is also returning an empty field.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that the USBVersion property is used. I can't remember ever having seen it populated.

Comment: @EBGreen Actually it is populated! which is why I am thinking something is missing. You can try the same snippet in powershell ise and run it to get what i got!

Comment: I ran it and there is no value for the property (or perhaps it is a null string I didn't check). If yours was populated, there would be a value there. Why do you say that it is populated?

Comment: Sorry I meant the property came but no value was returned, thats what i meant by populated. I cant find other materials regarding this in WMI. Powershell is not powerful enough to query a hardware then? btw when u ran this did u have a usb device inserted?

Comment: I had several USB devices returned. Populating a field like that is completely up to the hardware vendor. The field is there in WMI. If the hardware vendor does not have the firmware populate it then there isn't much to be done.

Comment: The USBVersion is contained in the DeviceDescriptor which is inside the Hardware. The DeviceDescriptor is queried to get that information. My understanding of WMI is that it is querying the h/w and not the firmware. Correct me if i am wrong :-)

Comment: Well, my understanding is that the device descripter is part of the firmware. I could be wrong too though. Regardless I can't ever remember having seen that property with a value in WMI.